# Retrieving a dynamically created fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

My code dynamically creates fragments in a tabbed view, I would like to access one of the fragments when the OnCreate activity is called.
I know that there are 2 methods of retrieving an existing fragment, one by ID and one by Tag.
How is it possible to mark the fragments when they are created to be retrieved later?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        if(extras !=null) {
            // ***Get Fragment Here***
        }
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new TabFragment1(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TabFragment2(), "TWO");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The FragmentPagerAdapter already caches the Fragments for you. Each fragment is assigned a tag, and then the FragmentPagerAdapter tries to call

```
findFragmentByTag
```

It only calls getItem if the result from findFragmentByTag is null. So you shouldn't have to cache the fragments yourself.

Also, you can get reference of your Fragment in FragmentPagerAdapter using findFragmentByTag() method. The name of the tag is generated this way:

```
private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int index)
{
     return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
}
```

where viewId is the id of ViewPager

Answer (score 0):

AmanSinghal's answer will work, I have an alternative approach. You can create an adapter with a method which returns the currently displayed fragment.

I implemented it here a few years ago: [PublicisedFragmentPagerAdapter](https://github.com/griffinjm/AndroidUtils/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ie/jgriffin/androidutils/view/PublicisedFragmentPagerAdapter.java)
Look at the `getCurrentPrimaryItem()` method